# how to pass action type redux in react navigation?

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-navigation

how to pass action type when login is succes in react navigation with redux ?

here my code...

```
import { Login } from '../constant/Constant'

import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
import dispatch from "redux/es/createStore";

export function login(data) {
    if (data.email === 'me') {
        //NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Route' });
        console.log("login success");
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch({type: 'Login'});
        };
    }else{
        console.log("login error");
    }
}
```

and this is my reducer.js, and how to pass action login to here, i try myself when login is success but cant passing action typelogin to here

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import { AppNavigator } from '../navigators/AppNavigator';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'
const firstAction       = AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Main');
const tempNavState      = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(firstAction);
const secondAction      =     AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Login');
const initialNavState   = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
    secondAction,
    tempNavState
)

function nav(state = initialNavState, action) {
    let nextState;
    switch (action.type){
        case 'Login':
            nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
                NavigationActions.back(),
                state
            );
            break;
        case 'Logout':
            nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
                NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: 'Login'}),
                state
            );
            break;
        default:
            nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
            break;

    }

    return nextState || state;
}

const initialAuthState  = { isLoggedIn: false };
```

//How To pass login from action.js to here

```
function auth(state = initialAuthState, action) {
    switch (action.type){
        case 'Login':
            console.log(action.type);
            return { ...state, isLoggedIn:true };
        case 'Logout':
            return { ...state, isLoggedIn:false};
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const AppReducer = combineReducers({
    nav,
    auth,
    form: formReducer
})

export default AppReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

can you paste `redux/es/createStore`, would like to see how `dispatch` method being exported

and what you can do is:

```
export function login(data) {
    if (data.email === 'me') {
        dispatch({type: 'Login'});
    }else{
        console.log("login error");
    }
}
```

have a look at http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html, i don't see any `store` in your code

after you combine the reducer into store, you can do something like this

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

let store = createStore(reducers); //connecting reducers to store

.
..
...

export dispatch = (action) => store.dispatch(action);
```

Comment: my store in app.js... and my problem is why when im success login, cant send type:'Login' in my reducers... it work when i click button then send type:'Login', but when success login cant send type:'Login'